# Computing the columns containing the largest two differences in two rows in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Suppose that I have two rows of numbers in Excel or Google Sheets, say

```
    1     2     3      4     5
A   6     4     9      12    0
B   8     6     10     15    4
```

I want to determine the columns that correspond to the two largest differences between the two rows of data.  For example, the differences of row B entries minus row A entries are 2, 2, 1, 3, 4.  Columns 4 and 5 contain the largest differences, and I want to determine this in Excel.  I.e., I want to have an expression that I can put in cells A6 and A7, respectively, that tell me 4 and 5 for these two differences.

I actually want to do something like this for dozens of rows and columns, so a solution that requires me manually typing in each row or each column is undesirable.  I'm not wedded to definitely using Excel or definitely using Google Sheets and can go back and forth between them, so a solution in either is fine.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: What have you tried?  And where have you run into trouble? This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 MATCH(  MAX(2:2-1:1),    2:2-1:1, 0), 
 MATCH(LARGE(2:2-1:1, 2), 2:2-1:1, 0)})
```

[image: 0]

---

for column names use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 CHAR(64+MATCH(  MAX(2:2-1:1),    2:2-1:1, 0)), 
 CHAR(64+MATCH(LARGE(2:2-1:1, 2), 2:2-1:1, 0))})
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

The formula in Q3 on this sample sheet will at least help with getting the largest difference.  I'll think a bit more about how to maybe get the second biggest difference.

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BFJOa3rhy9gLFA_nJAVyOSu0LDW4j5SNA308VmB-M84/edit?usp=sharing)

Matt